# Failing to populate a ListView with an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

Trying to get this working... it loads up fine, even tells the application that it completed getting all the data. It does not populate the listview though.

The data response inside mArrayList.toString(): [A, B, C, D]

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity";
private boolean mAlternateTitle = false;
ListView lv;
private ArrayList<Show> mArrayList;
ShowsAdapter adapter;
AlertDialog mAlertDialog;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mArrayList = new ArrayList<Show>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ShowsAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mArrayList);

    ShowsList show_list = new ShowsList();
    show_list.execute();

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new ListClickListener());
}

private class ShowsList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Show>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh).setTitle(R.string.fetching_new).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Show> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity$ShowList$doInBackground";
        try {
            for (Show show : Show.getShows()) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, show.toString());
                mArrayList.add(show);
            };
            return mArrayList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext()).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle(R.string.server_down_title).setMessage(R.string.server_down_message).setPositiveButton(R.string.app_quit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            }).show();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<Show> show_list) {
        if (mAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
            mAlertDialog.dismiss();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

private class ListClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Show show = mArrayList.get(i);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked on a list item: " + show.title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private class ShowsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Show> {
    final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity$ShowsAdapter";
    public ShowsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Show> shows) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, shows);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Show show = this.getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_row_show, parent, false);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.show_title)).setText(show.title);
        //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, (String)((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.show_title)).getText());
        //((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.episode_number)).setText(episode.getGrayLine());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Just in case it could be an issue with the layout [main.xml]:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

list_show_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
            android:textSize="17.0dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/show_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.0dip"
            android:text="Show Title"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            />

    <TextView
            android:textStyle="italic" android:textColor="#ff666666"
            android:id="@+id/episode_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:text="Episode Number" android:layout_weight="1.0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is it giving you your alertdialog?

Comment: The alert dialog does show "Fetching data" - the string I set for it. When it's completed, the alertdialog actually dismisses without errors.

Comment: are you seeing this log output in your logcat? (Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, mArrayList.toString());)

Comment: 04-21 18:09:00.898: DEBUG/MainActivity$ShowList$onPostExecute(1045): [A, B, C, D]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set fill_parent on the layout_height of the root element of list_row_show.xml layout.